# How to Filter rows based on User Input search value

Tags: c#, sql, select

i have question about a code in  this article:

[How to display rows based on search value which works for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378759/how-to-display-rows-based-on-search-value-which-works-for-multiple-columns/27311366#27311366)

in line  dv.RowFilter = "col1='" + ss + "' and col2>=10";

how we can use only search value and select  1 row in result?

like we have a column: name and just showing search value in name column?

my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string ss = searchbox.Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;
                           Initial Catalog=db3;Integrated Security=True");
   sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from phone", con);
   sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "phone");

   DataView dv = sDs.Tables[0].DefaultView;

   dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables["phone"];
   dv.RowFilter = "name='" + ss;   
}
```

**@hamed2011 Problem Solved**

Comment: I don't get what you are asking.

Comment: @hamed2011: Edit your question with your comment, (post that code in question)

Comment: if you can't comment, reedit to make this a complete question by itself.

Comment: What error are you receiving or what is the issue?

Comment: i just want to  finding a name in "name column" but i use code and above and got empty row or 2 row with same value! so any true code can help me

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem relies in the last sentence:

```
 dv.RowFilter = "name='" + ss;
```

You forgot about closing the quotation. It should be

```
 dv.RowFilter = "name='" + ss+"'";
```

However - about the sample from attached link - please, please, please never ever query database using string concatenation. It's probably most common security flaw.

Read about using query parameters here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Edit: About the row duplication, I have suspitions about old data in dataset. Have you tried to recreate dataset or just clear it before load?

And proper query for ensure no data duplication would be

```
select distinct name from phone
```

Comment: i used it("name='" + ss+"'";) but i told you guys that get result 2 row with same value. i want when user typed alex row by name of Alex only viewing and in 1 row not duplicate

Comment: What you need is distinct. You can change database query or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965134/calling-distinct-on-datarow-collection

Comment: in entire table there is one row with name of alex and this code show duplicated result and we need to distinct???  i think the  code is wrong  ...  anyway is there any better code for use sql select queries for search in datagridview in c#?